# Program not working in declared directory path, only in current directory

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm writing a program that takes all the files from a directory declared in the command line. The command line takes 2 arguments, the directory path and a optional flag "-s" which spits out directory information in non-decreasing order if applied. I'm 90% done but my program only spits out files and file information from the current directory, not the directory specified in the command line. Any advice would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int mygetFstat(char *name);
char *removeWhiteSpaces(char *str);

#define PATH 1
#define FLAG 2
#define LEN 10
#define STRLEN 54
#define MAXLEN 100

    struct stat fileStat;
    time_t t;
    struct tm lt;
    char timbuf[MAXLEN];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
FILE *ptr;
char myBuf[MAXLEN]; 
char filename[MAXLEN];
 char finalfile[MAXLEN]; 
char length;
 char str[MAXLEN];
 char cmd[MAXLEN];


if ((dir = opendir (argv[PATH])) != NULL) {
  // print all the files and directories within directory

   if(argv[FLAG] != NULL){
     if(strcmp(argv[FLAG], "-s") == 0){
       system("ls -al | sort -k5n >> tempfile.txt");

       //sprintf(finalfile, "cd %s | ls -al | sort -k5n >> tempfile.txt", (char *)argv[PATH]);
       // printf("\nfinal file = %s\n", finalfile);
       //    system(finalfile);

        if(NULL == (ptr = fopen("tempfile.txt","rw"))){
         printf("\nCan't open file.\n");
          exit(1);
        }

        while(!feof(ptr)){             // loop through every line in tempfile.txt
      fgets(myBuf, MAXLEN, ptr);
      if(strlen(myBuf) > LEN){     // I chose 11 here because some lines were only 10 characters
                                   // And they were unnecessary. 

      length = strlen(myBuf);      // Grabs length of entire line from ptr

      strncpy(filename, myBuf + STRLEN, length);           // the file names start at bit position 54, 
      if((filename[0] == '.') && (filename[1] != '.') && (strlen(filename) != 2)){
        removeWhiteSpaces(filename);
        mygetFstat(filename); 
      }
     }
    }
    system("rm tempfile.txt");
        exit(1);

     }else{
       printf("Error: Flag not recognized.\n");
       return 0;
     }
    }else{

    while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
      if((ent->d_name[0] == '.') && (ent->d_name[1] != '.') && (strlen(ent->d_name) != 1))
    mygetFstat(ent->d_name);

    }
  closedir (dir);  
  }
    } else {
  // could not open directory

   printf("No such File or Directory.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}

int mygetFstat(char *name)
{
  // Function for finding info about files.

    int file = 0;
        if((file = open(name,O_RDONLY)) < -1)
            return 1;

    if(fstat(file,&fileStat) < 0)
        return 1;

    printf("Information for %s\n",name);
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("File Size: \t\t%d bytes\n",fileStat.st_size);

    // Adjusts time to display date. Not just seconds from epoch

    t = fileStat.st_mtime;
    localtime_r(&t, &lt);
    strftime(timbuf, sizeof(timbuf), "%c", &lt);
    printf("Date Last Modified: \t%s\n",timbuf);
    printf("\n");

    //return 0;
}

char *removeWhiteSpaces(char *str){ //removes white spaces from input
  char *end;
  while(isspace(*str)) str++;
  if(*str == 0)
    return str;

  end = str + strlen(str)-1;
  while(end > str && isspace(*end)) end--;
  *(end+1) = 0;
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ent->d_name` only contains the name of the entry in that directory. It does not include the full path to the entry.

If the first argument is "folder1" and there are files "file-1.txt" and "file-2.txt" in that directory, `ent->d_name` will be "file-1.txt" and "file-2.txt". You need to pass "folder1/file-1.txt" to `mygetFstat()`, not just "file-1.txt".

You should change the `while` loop to:

```
while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
   if((ent->d_name[0] == '.') && (ent->d_name[1] != '.') && (strlen(ent->d_name) != 1))
   {
      strcpy(filename, argv[PATH]);
      strcat(filename, "/");
      strcat(filename, ent->d_name);
      mygetFstat(filename);
   }
}
```

**Update**

I would add a function

```
int is_dot_or_dot_dot(char const* entryName)
{
   return (strcmp(entryName, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(entryName, "..") == 0);
}
```

and change the code inside the `while` loop to:

```
while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
  if ( is_dot_or_dot_dot(ent->d_name) )
  {
     continue;
  }
  strcpy(filename, argv[PATH]);
  strcat(filename, "/");
  strcat(filename, ent->d_name);
  mygetFstat(filename);
}
```

Comment: I understand your logic and I appreciate the response. But i cannot get your code segment to work. it keeps Core dumping when I run it.

Comment: Oops. I'm an idiot. Disregard that comment ^^ Thank you for your input this worked perfectly!!

Comment: @user3600601 glad it worked. I'm still confused by the `if` statement. Are you trying to say ignore `.` and `..`?

Comment: Yes! I do not want the info for the current directory(.) and the previous directory(..) so i rule those out with that if. Also if you have any input on this line:   system("ls -al | sort -k5n >> tempfile.txt"); I'm not very good with unix commands and this only returns the files from the current directory, not the directory path. Any more advice would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Keep your code, do a chdir right after you open the directory:

```
if ((dir = opendir (argv[PATH])) != NULL) {
// print all the files and directories within directory
    // Change the working directory to the one given.
    if (chdir(argv[PATH]) == -1) { 
         perror(argv[PATH]); exit(1);
     }
```

P.S I would recommend using perror but you have to include errno.h.

Improvement on the rest of your code.

```
       system("ls -al | sort -k5n >> tempfile.txt");
```

While you can do that it would be a faster way to insert it into a linked list sorting it as you insert them. But if you want to keep it see below for improvements.

The whole point of this project is to use system calls.See http://www.albany.edu/~csi402/pdfs/lect_10.pdf

```
        while(!feof(ptr)){             // loop through every line in tempfile.txt
          fgets(myBuf, MAXLEN, ptr);
```

feof is not reliable, use

```
       while( fgets (myBuf, MAXLEN, ptr)!=NULL ){
```